# Automation of culling process

Tags: lightroom, adobe, automation, plugin

Today I was going through your website for basically reducing the time made over doing the culling process in the Lightroom and found your website.

Basically, we work on wedding images where we are doing a regular culling process and do the selection of around 60-70% good pose by bride and groom and also avoid repeat same kind of photos.

Please confirm if I can achieve something like this with the help of any plugin or technology.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi Azim and welcome to Photo.se! Could you indicate what you've tried so far? Did you search Google? Did you search this site? Did you find something which is similar to what you want? And what exactly do you want to achieve? Are you looking for some plugin that can automatically cull "bad" images? If so, how do you want it to know what is good and bad? Please edit your question to include details and your own research.

Comment: Relevant: [Methods (mechanics) to select a set of pictures from large amounts](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/76388)

Answer (score 3):

If I understood your question correctly, you are looking for a tool to reduce the time spent during the culling process.

You can use software like [FilterPixel](https://filterpixel.com) to cull your photos automatically. (Full disclosure, I am the founder and CEO of FilterPixel)

### How does this work?

**Step 1:**

**Import Files & Create Your Project**

When you come from a photo shoot, you can create a project & can drag and drop the folder containing Raw Files or JPEG's into FilterPixel App.

[image]

**Step 2:**

**Use AI To Filter Out Bad Photos**

The app automatically find photos with less focus quality & eye quality and filter them out into accepted, rejected, warnings & unlabelled.

1. Accepted: FilterPixel AI provides control to the photographer to accept any photo, so it doesn't accept any photo by default.
2. Rejected: Photos that are completely out of focus & have closed eyes are classified into rejected view automatically.
3. Warnings: Photos with minor quality issues such as soft focus are classified into warning view automatically.
4. Unlabelled: Photos without any issues are classified into Unlabelled view automatically.

[image]

**Step 3:**

**Quickly Select Your Best Photos With AI Metrics & FaceViews**

Every photo is provided with a quality metrics which can be used to narrow down your selections.

[image]

**Step 4:**

**Export Photos to Lightroom or Local Folder**

After your culling is done, you can export your photos to Lightroom or to a local folder on your hardrive.

You can find more about it at [filterpixel.com](https://filterpixel.com).

Answer (score 1):

You do not need plugin for this purpose. Moreover current level of software/AI is not enough to "say" which image is good which is bad.
The method I use is sample and quite strait. You select Survey mode: **View->Survey** or press `N`. Then **Photo->Auto Advance** to make LR switch to the next image when you rate current one. And use numbers from 1 to 5 to rate (usual values are 1 for "bad", 5 for "very good". After this create smart collection which will include all images with rate 3 or more (for example).

Et voila, you have all selected/good images in one collection.

Comment: Control + A, Delete?  A is for Auto.

Comment: @xiota, I am sorry, I do not get it. Also if you are in smart collection LR do not permit deletion.

Comment: Easiest "automatic" culling is delete everything.  (Specificity of the operation would be expected to be good because majority of images most people produce are not good.)  I don't use LR, and this inability to delete seems like a major flaw.

Comment: @xiota, only if you are in smart collection. When you go to any other "view" you are free to remove (from LR) or delete (from disk and LR)

Answer (score 0):

I use a plain image viewer (Gwenview) with four keyboard shortcuts defined on four horizontally aligned keys on my keyboard. These are `Previous`/`Next`/`100% zoom`/`Delete`. `Delete` automatically goes to the next picture. In normal operation index/middle/ring fingers rest on the `Next`/`100% zoom`/`Delete`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if someone is still looking for a solution to this, but we've been working on a tool that addresses this exact problem: [AfterShoot](https://aftershoot.co/).

AfterShoot will automatically go through all your images and star-rate and color code the keepers vs rejects.
Since everyone has a different workflow, it allows for option to choose what star rating or color code is to be assigned to the keepers vs rejects.

The keepers and rejects are also keyworded for locating them easily in LightRoom.

[image: AfterShoot Keywords and Star Ratings]

This is also extremely useful if you shoot a lot of duplicates (that OP mentioned that they do), as AfterShoot can also identify the duplicate images and mark the best image(s) from a set of duplicates!

To use the app, you simply select the folder containing your RAW/JPEG images that you need to cull through:

[image: Folder Selection]

Select your preferences for the cull:

[image: Filter Selection]

Sit back and relax:
[image: Culling]

Here's also a quick video showcasing the complete culling workflow with AfterShoot:

[[image: Video thumbnail]

AfterShoot: Workflow](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GMgxRYt61gc)

We're currently in beta and if anyone wants to try the app for themselves, you can head over to the site and download it for free!

https://aftershoot.co/

Comment: Are you basically a copy of filterpixel? You even use [the same drawings](https://aftershoot.co/static/media/app_1.d2fbd55f.png)?

Comment: Hey Saaru, not to point fingers at who is a copy of what; you can look at when the FB page of AfterShoot and Filterpixel was created. That should tell you more about things :) 

https://www.facebook.com/aftershootco/
https://www.facebook.com/filterpixel

Thanks again!

Comment: Well, I'm not here to figure out who stole what. Can you perhaps indicate how your product helps the OP in a better way than FilterPixel? Otherwise it feels it's more like an advertisement and not an answer to the question.

Comment: Yeah, definitely! OP mentioned that they click a lot of similar pictures and they have trouble in finding out the best images that are to be delivered. We can help them with just that!

AfterShoot can group duplicate and similar pictures together and also decide upon the keeper image(s) from those duplicates.  Based on the feedback from our beta testing, in an average wedding shoot, AfterShoot brings down the number of images to cull from 6000 to 2000.

Comment: You seem to miss the point. Photo.SE is not a free advertising platform. It's fine to post an answer,showing how the software you work on can help the OP (while disclosing your affiliation). Your answer does not read like an answer, but like a sponsored post. On top of that of that, you've posted the [exact same text](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/119389/9161) on another question *and* you're advertising it in the [comments](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/108645/automation-of-culling-process/119390?noredirect=1#comment229642_108646) as well. I don't appreciate that.

Comment: In contrast, the answer from FilterPixel shows some screenshots that actually address the OP's question, wihtout excessive product name placement.

Comment: Alright, I understand. My apologies. I have updated the answer to reflect the solution to OP's question instead of it looking like an advertisement. I'll be doing the same with my other answer as well. 

Thanks and let me know if it still looks off.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd never trust a computer to determine if an image is acceptable or not.

For years, I've used a three pass method where each pass takes longer per image, but has fewer images remaining. In the old days, I used the same basic process on prints from film, but here I'll describe how I do it in Lightroom.

Before starting, I recommend at least 24-48 hours before looking at your images. This gives your mind a little time to forget its expectations so you can look at the images for what they are rather than what you expected them to be.

First is the pick/reject pass. This is extremely fast because all you're doing is giving your gut reaction. Only 1-2 seconds per image. The question I ask is "Is this image worth my time?" You'll eliminate anything with major technical issues, blinking subjects, and anything you just don't like. On a 1000 shot shoot, I generally eliminate 500-600 of the images and it takes only 15-20 minutes.

Next, filter to only show the pics, select them all and mark them 3 stars. The work through the group and ask yourself "Is this image better than my average or worse than my average?" I keep my fingers on 2 and 4 and either leave them alone or increase or decrease the rating accordingly. This process takes about 10 minutes and I end up with about 100 3 star and 200-250 each for 2 and 4 stars.

Finally, filter for 4's. These should be the best shots you got, and now you look through them and ask "Is there anything special that sets this image apart?" I'll generally revise a few of them down because they aren't up to scratch, but generally about a third of them will be marked 5 stars.

When all is said and done, I preset the 5 star images to the customer along with anything in the 4's that I need to get proper coverage. In a pinch, I might grab a 3 if it's something too important to miss, but in the end I might present 75-100 images to the customer per 1000 shots and the culling process takes less than an hour.